# Visualizar Datos almacenados en firebase en un activity Android Studio con un list view

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Hola quería hacerles una consulta lo que pasa es que tengo datos guardados en firebase de la siguiente manera users que son mis distintos usurios y dentro de estos usuarios existe un campo score que contiene otros datos [image: esta es la de usurios][image: Esta es la de score]

Lo que quisiera es que los datos de score salgan en el list view que hice en mi actividad con su usuario correspondiente
 relice un codigo pero cada vez que corro se cierra automaticamente mi aplicación creo que es un problema de que no reconoce al usuario si alguien me pudiera ayudar estaría agradecido

tengo un metodo inicilizar firebase donde creo que esta el error

```
private void inicializarFirebase() {
    firebaseAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()== null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ingreso.class));
    }

    FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    databaseReference = database.getReference("Users").child(user.getUid());




}
```

y esta es la parte del list view

```
 private void listarDatos() {
    databaseReference.child("Score").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listscore.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot objetsnatshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Score s=objetsnatshot.getValue(Score.class);
                listscore.add(s);

                scoreArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Score>(resultados.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listscore );
                listvscore.setAdapter(scoreArrayAdapter);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola Julio, bienvenido. Podrias agregar cual es el error que hace que tu aplicacion se cierre? seguramente lo podras encontrar mirando en el logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione  les dejo el codigo  si a alguien le mas le puede ayudar,  el problema era que no le leía correctamente  el id por eso se cerraba y lo que llevaría a un NullPointerExceptionintento de llamada getUid().  le corregi esto y tambien la lista del Array

```
 private void listaderesultado() {


    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    usersRef = db.getReference("Users" ).child(auth.getUid()).child("Score");

    usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            ArrayList<String> listado= new ArrayList<String>();

            listado.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot objetsnatshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){



                Score s=objetsnatshot.getValue(Score.class);
                String cuento=s.cuento;
                String apro=s.estado_Aprovacion;
                String tiem=s.tiempo;
                listado.add("--------"+"Registro"+"-------");
                listado.add("Nivel: "+cuento);
                listado.add("Calificacion: "+apro);
                listado.add("tiempo: "+tiem);




                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(resultados.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listado);
                listvscore.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(resultados.this,"No salio nada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });
}
```